# Compare two tables and select values not present in table 1 (based on time)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table one like below:

```
TimeIn      TimeOut
-------------------
07:30       12:30
13:30       16:30
```

I have table two like below:

```
TimeIn      TimeOut
-------------------
07:00       07:06
07:10       08:30
08:45       12:45
13:55       15:30
16:15       16:50
```

Table one is the shift policy of an employee and table two is the attendance timings of an employee.

I would like to know on what timings this employee was outside on shift policy hours?

**Expected output:**

```
TimeIn      TimeOut
-------------------
08:30       08:45
13:30       13:55
15:30       16:15
```

The query I was trying which is not working:

```
SELECT InTime AS TimeIn, OutTime AS TimeOut FROM HR.GetRegisterList(@EmpId, @Date)
EXCEPT
SELECT FromTime AS TimeIn, ToTime AS TimeOut FROM HR.GetEmployeeDateShiftDetails(@EmpId, @Date)
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I will update question with my query.

Comment: How you are deriving the 'Expected Output' - timeout goes to timein and vice-versa?

Comment: Your query doesn't work, because it just compares the rows of the two tables. How about describing an algorithm first, and then try to implement it as an SQL statement?

Comment: My intention is to get timings where employee was outside office on office shift hours.

Comment: Your task is clear. Can you try to translate it in terms of your data structures?

Comment: Table 1 and Table 2 may be considered as examples. I am very newbie :-(

Comment: Search for sql server window functions, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet should do the work, I had to make a modification in the `Shift Policy` `table` - added a `column` `ShiftType` -

```
declare @shiftpolicy table(time_in varchar(10),time_out varchar(10),ShiftType NVARCHAR(2))
insert into @shiftpolicy values ('07:30','12:30','M'),('13:30','16:30','A')
declare @attendance table(time_in varchar(10),time_out varchar(10))
insert into @attendance values ('07:00','07:06'),('07:10','08:30'),('08:45','12:45'),('13:55','15:30'),('16:15','16:50')
select * from @shiftpolicy
select * from @attendance
SELECT * FROM
(
    select case 
                when row = 1 then 
                    case when time_in > DefTimeIn then DefTimeIn--+' - '+convert(nvarchar(50),time_in)
                    else ''
                    end
                when row = last
                    then case when time_out < DefTimeOut then time_out--+' - '+convert(nvarchar(50),DefTimeOut)
                    else ''
                    end
                else ''
                    end--*
            [Out]
                ,case 
                when row = 1 then 
                    case when time_in > DefTimeIn then time_in
                    else ''
                    end
                when row = last
                    then case when time_out < DefTimeOut then DefTimeOut
                    else ''
                    end
                else ''
                    end--,*
                [IN]
    --select *
    from 
    (
        select last_value(row) over (partition by ShiftType order by ShiftType) last ,*
        from 
        (
            select ts.time_in DefTimeIn,ts.time_out DefTimeOut,ts.ShiftType,ta.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ts.time_in,ShiftType ORDER BY ta.time_in) row
                ,lead(ta.time_in,1,0) over (PARTITION BY ts.time_in,ShiftType ORDER BY ta.time_in) TimeOt
            from @shiftpolicy ts
            inner join @attendance ta 
                on ta.time_in <= ts.time_out and ta.time_out >= ts.time_in
        )t
    )ta
    --order by ShiftType desc

    union

    select time_out,lead from
    (
        select ts.time_in DefTimeIn,ts.time_out DefTimeOut,ts.ShiftType,ta.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ts.time_in,ShiftType ORDER BY ta.time_in) row
            ,lead(ta.time_in,1,0) over (PARTITION BY ts.time_in,ShiftType ORDER BY ta.time_in) lead
            --,lag(ta.time_in,1,0) over (PARTITION BY ts.time_in,ShiftType ORDER BY ta.time_in)
            --,last_value(ta.time_out) over(PARTITION BY ts.time_in,ShiftType ORDER BY shiftType)
        from @shiftpolicy ts
        inner join @attendance ta 
            on ta.time_in <= ts.time_out and ta.time_out >= ts.time_in
    )t
)TA
where ([OUT] <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND [IN] <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND [out] <> '' AND [in] <> '0'
order by 1
```